# Арифметика с плавающей запятой

Tags: c++

Помогите, проблема в следующем, есть вот такой код (можно организовать и цикле), первые два действия "-" дают правильный результат, а вот последнее выдает result=3.

6429192995513e-017

```
double x1=0.6;
double x2=0.03;
double x3=0.009;
double result=0.639;
result=result-x1;
result=result-x2;
result=result-x3;
```

Comment: Если есть на земле Ад, то этот Ад называется вычисления с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Конечные десятичные дроби в двоичной системе исчисления могут стать бесконечными, отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: Если у вас есть желание подробнее разобраться как работает плавающая арифметика и почему возникает погрешность рекомендую ознакомиться с проектом
[ECA](http://ru.exploringcomputerarithmetic.org/articles/fp/IEEE-754/basics/). Сайт ещё довольно сырой, но уже приоткроет завесу тайны плавающей арифметики.

Answer (score 5):

Ничего удивительного - арифметика с плавающей запятой она такая. В зависимости от того в каком порядке производились расчеты, окончательный результат может немного отличаться от ожидаемого. Плюс вступают в силу округления - совершенно необязательно, что компьютер будет, скажем, 32 битные числа с плавающей запятой не переводить в 64 или 80 битные, считать результат, а потом перегонять его обратно.

В данном случае, если нужно понять получили ли мы ноль, то нужно просто ввести условие, что  `result < epsilon`. epsilon - это какое-то очень маленькое число, которое и будет нам говорить о неразличимости плавающих чисел. Его можно подобрать или практическим путем (учитывая ту точность вычислений, которая нам нужна), или взять его уже готовым при помощи ф-ций библиотеки языка или из заголовочных файлов.

См. статью [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon#Approximation_using_C.2B.2B)

Comment: каноническая ссылка для таких вопросов: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html